# Drag object in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I achieve this dragging effect? I am using ActionScript3. 
http://l2on.net/swf/MapView2.swf

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself yet? Perhaps using [ActionScript MouseEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html)? Please attempt the problem beforehand for both your own learning and so we have a better idea of how you're approaching this.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you have problems with? This is a standard drag&drop with limits, as far as I can tell. Or is there some special functionality that you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a very standard drag drop functionality:-

You can use startDrag function at MouseDown and stopDrag at MouseUp event

like:

```
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMapDragging);
 this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMapDragging);

 function startMapDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
    map.startDrag();
 }

 function stopMapDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
    map.stopDrag();
  }
```